# IOS Game Center Achievements

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, game-center

How can I save not uploaded achievements through NSCoding protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ( ! [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: myInterestingObject
                   toFile: reallyCoolArchivePath ] ) {      
    NSLog(@" archiver write failed.");
} else {
    NSLog(@" archiver write SUCCEEDED.");
}
```

Get them back with NSKeyedUnarchiver.